# In Verilog, whether always @(*) expects the actions to be completed in 1 clock period?

Tags: verilog

In Verilog, my peripherals are running at 100MHz = 10 nano seconds. In once `always@(positive)` block I was trying to do operations that exceeds 10 nano seconds. I rearranged the code so that the operations are performed now in an `always@(*)` block. Even now I have the same issue and my bitstream is not getting generated. So my question is why should always block should worry about the period ? as synchronization between clock and `always@(*)` block is not expected

Comment: Without more details, I cant completely answer the question. However, it seems like from what you are saying that some logic in your design is not completing fast enough. It doesnt matter how you rearrange the logic as your current description doesnt meet the timing needed (so long as the synthesis tool produces roughly the same output at least; which it will from your description of what you did). Either you need to parallelize more of your design or it might not be possible to meet the timing you need. Remember, you are describing hardware, nothing changes if you dont change your design.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. So you mean even in case of the always@(*) block, the timing should be such that the block execution should complete in 1 clock period?

Comment: Yes, because the `always @(*)` is representing cominbational logic. Now, while in simulation that logic might take no time, in real systems, it takes some time. If that time is greater than the clock period minus setup time for the registers in the system, the design will not work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... It makes a lot of sense...

Comment: @Unn Would you like to turn those comments into an answer, pointing out the propagation delay of real electronics. Then it could be accepted/upvoted, thanks.

Comment: Note that this is true even in the simulator. If the next trigger arrives when you're still doing the operations (e.g. if you add a delay) then you miss the trigger. If that happens in synthesis... I guess the synthesizer might just reject your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I cannot be certain that this is your problem without knowing more about your code and the synthesis results; it is possible you are running into a timing problem where the logic in your design cannot complete in a single 100MHz cycle.

When creating a sequential designs, one must always be aware that real logic has propagation delay. This means that the more logic is in between to registers (ie, that needs to be completed in a single clock cycle), the longer that logic will take in real time. Thus, what it seems you might be facing is that the amount of calculations you are trying to do in a single step takes longer than the clock period (minus the setup time of the registers that store the result).

Its also important to note that while changing your design from using a single `always @(posedge)` to an `always @(*)` will not result in any major changes in the synthesized result as the design you are describing is effectively the same (ie, a bunch of logic doing some calculations, followed by a set of registers to store the result). While simulating the design might be different, the hardware synthesized from the code will be very similar, thus the problem will remain.

In order to fix such timing problems, you can either break the logic into smaller pieces and pipeline it or you can change the design to bew iterative (taking multiple clock cycles). It is possible you might be able to change the logic in the design to convert long chains into tree structures or other things to try and break up the longest paths through the logic (thus decreasing overall propagation delay), but depending on the design, that might not be possible.